# Translation of Counter-free automata into Linear Temporal Logic

Tags: reference-request, automata-theory, linear-temporal-logic

There is a well-known equivalence between counter-free automata and Linear Temporal Logic (which is cited for example by [1]). However, I cannot find a concrete way to obtain an LTL formula from a counter-free automaton.

Is there any reference that shows such a translation?

[1] Wolfgang Thomas, Safety- and Liveness-properties in Propositional Temporal Logic: Characterisation and Decidability, Mathematical Problems in Computation Theory, Volume 21, 1988

Comment: Have you tried to look at translations from counter-free automaton into FO[<]? It is known that LTL = FO[<], so maybe you can find something in this direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the translation is shown in:
Volker Diekert and Paul Gastin. "First-order definable languages." (2008)
http://www.lsv.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/DG-WT08.pdf

And it goes via a characterization of $LTL$ as $FO[<]$.

Comment: This paper seems fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to provide the same answer as for [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49014),
but this was proved in [1, Theorem 3.1].

[1] J. Cohen, D. Perrin and J.-É. Pin, [On the expressive power of temporal logic for finite words](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009390005H), *J. Comput. System Sci.* **46** (1993), 271-294.